# Turn all Text() on swift app to the same color in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-playground

I have used the Text("") object multiple times in my Swift Playground app but I want to change the color of all of them to a specific color (white) without changing each Text property one by one. Is there a way to do this?

**Disclaimer:** I am programming in a Swift Playground

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a custom `ViewModifier`

```
struct MyTextModifier: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
    }
}
```

Then you can apply it to `Text` where needed, and you only need to change it in the ViewModifier struct.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Your Text")
            .modifier(MyTextModifier())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create your own `View` whose body is a `Text` and that has a `color` property that you use as the `foregroundColor` of your `Text`. If you make the `color` property `static`, it will apply to all instances of your `View`.

You just need to make sure you use `ColoredText` instead of `Text` in all places where you want the same color and if you change `ColoredText.color`, all instances will apply the new text color.

```
struct ColoredText: View {
    @State static var color: Color = .primary
    @State var text: String

    var body: some View {
        Text(text)
            .foregroundColor(ColoredText.color)
    }
}
```

Comment: Add 
init(_ text: String) {
        self.text = text
    }
to avoid parameter label. and can be used as ColoredText("text")

Answer (score 3):

if you want to change ALL you can use this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello World")
            Text("aha")
            Button(action: {}) {
                  Text("Tap here")
              }
            }.colorInvert()
        .colorMultiply(Color.red)
    }
  }
```

Comment: Changes the background color of whole view but the text remains same. Something i was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If your whole app is SwiftUI then you can apply the foregroundColor modifier at the root. This will turn all the text red in the app, unless you specify otherwise using foregroundColor where you need it.

```
struct MyApp: App {

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            MyAppContentView()
                .foregroundColor(.red)
        }
    }
}  

struct MyAppContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("This is red - the default")
        Text("This is blue")
            .foregroundColor(.blue)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can this be applied to all previews as well?